# Mosquitto Bridge topic setting ignoring pattern

Tags: config, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a setup with two MQTT Brokers (Mosquitto), remote and local.
Remote handles a lot of traffic, local is supposed to act as a bridge and only forward a small subset of remote's topics.
So far, this is my mosquitto.conf for broker local:

```
connection bridge
address remote.com
notifications false
topic test/1 in 0
```

From what I understood, that configuration would make the local broker connect to remote and only subscribe to `test/1`.
Still, when subscribing to '#' of local broker, all of remotes messages arrive through local, not only `test/1`.

Is there any way to make my bridge forward only one certain topic or topic tree from the broker remote?

Comment: Did you do some experimentation before arriving at this config? If so I'd suggest adding `cleansession true` (after `connection bridge`); you can remove it after a successful connection if needed. From [the docs](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html): "If you are using bridges with cleansession set to false (the default), then you may get unexpected behaviour from incoming topics if you change what topics you are subscribing to".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Brits kindly explained in his comment, all the topics were coming through since on my first bridge attempt, I used '#' as the pattern.
That pattern seems to have persistet in all subsequent connections, until I used `cleansession true` once.

Thanks for the help.